# Why does passing custom props to a MUI styled element cause a DOM element warning to appear?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm working with mui v5 in React with Typescript. I'm attempting to style a div, but am getting the following error in the console:

"Warning: React does not recognize the `openFilterDrawer` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `openfilterdrawer` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element."

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
  type ChipsContainerProps = {
    openFilterDrawer: boolean
  }

 const ChipStyled = {
    Container: styled('div')<ChipsContainerProps>(
      ({ theme, openFilterDrawer }) => ({
          //leaving out irrelevant theme code
          ...(openFilterDrawer && {
            transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
              easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
              duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
            }),
            marginLeft: 0,
            paddingLeft: '0rem',
          }),
        },        
      }),
    ),
  }
```

Comment: Did yoy try 'openfilterdrawer' in lower case??

Comment: Yes, when I do that I end up with a new error: "Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `openfilterdrawer`."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that MUI is forwarding the `openFilterDrawer` prop that you're passing to the underlying `div`, and since `openFilterDrawer` is not a valid prop for `div`s, React is throwing that warning.

To clear the warning, you should pass an object containing a `shouldForwardProps` function to filter the prop from the resulting `div`.  For example:

```
const ChipStyled = {
  Container: styled("div", {
    shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "openFilterDrawer" // <-- Here
  })<ChipsContainerProps>(({ theme, openFilterDrawer }) => ({
    //leaving out irrelevant theme code
    ...(openFilterDrawer && {
      transition: theme.transitions.create("margin", {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
      }),
      marginLeft: 0,
      paddingLeft: "0rem"
    })
  }))
};
```

Comment: I believe the version of `styled` that is included with MUI >= 5.10, handles this for you by default on `div`s, but anything below that does not, but I could be wrong.  It's something that I just noticed between the two versions in codesandbox.

Answer (score 0):

An example using MUI version 5+

```js
export const PaperContainer = styled(Paper, {
  shouldForwardProp: prop => prop !== 'gridArea',
  name: 'PaperContainer',
})<{ gridArea: GridArea }>(({ theme, gridArea }) => ({
  gridArea,
  padding: theme.spacing(6),
  overflow: 'hidden',
}));
```